# Rails 2 - named_scope :include, :joins and selecting specific columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, associations, named-scope

I was wondering if it's possible to use :include in named_scope but to specify only specific columns to :include?

Currently I use the following:

```
class ProductOverwrite < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    named_scope :with_name, :include => :product

    def name
        produt.name
    end
end
```

But i'm wondering if I can select specific columns from the product table instead of selecting the entire set of columns which I obviously don't need.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something rails does out of the box.

You could 'piggy back' the attribute

```
named_scope :with_product_name, :joins => :product, :select => 'product_overwrites.*, products.name as piggy_backed_name'

def product_name
  read_attribute(:piggy_backed_name) || product.name
end
```

If it is possible for a `ProductOverwrite` to have no product, then you'd need a left join rather than the default inner join.